# Can a vent an AC through a screen window?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a screen window, and I'm not allowed to move the screen or cut part of the screen out. If I just put the vent hose on the screen (pointing outwards) using tape or something, will that break/melt the screen eventually?

Comment: balance the cost of breaking the rules with the comfort such breaking provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any good tape will eventually get gummy and clog into a screen and when you try to remove it, it could tear the screen. I try getting some nylon thread or fishing line and "stitch" the vent to the screen. You'd need one of those curved sewing needles, about a three cm one similar to the ones shown below and a needle nose pliers would give you a better hold on the needle.You'll be ale to remove the hose  easily when the time comes.

[image]

You could also just mount, tape, the vent hose to some heavy cardboard that fits tight into the window against the screen.

Comment: Could you expand on the "nylon thread" and "fishing line" idea? I'm having a hard time picture how I'd be able to wrap the fishing line through the whose and vent screen and back from the outside of the screen?

Comment: @student010101  I take it that you're not on the ground floor so I edited my answer.

Comment: Ah yes I am on the second floor.